# SSRS Frame around several Charts?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a dashboard and wanted to add a Frame/ Border/ Signifier around a series of seperate charts to show they are related to each other. For the life of me I can't sort out how to do this.

An example would be the Cost Per Year section in the lower left [image]

There are 4 gauges, and 4 bar charts. I am doing something similar, well, attempting to do something similar

Comment: Sorry don't have an answer but, This looks awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a rectangle,  put your gauges, charts, etc inside the rectangle, then you can add text boxes, borders, background colours to the rectangle.

the rectangle can grow to contain what ever is in it

Comment: Okay thank you, I will sort out how to create a rectangle now.